# Como posso inserir os resultados de uma consulta numa outra tabela?

Tags: mysql, query, inserir

Estou a executar a seguinte consulta à base de dados directamente a partir do [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php):

```sql
SELECT 
  shop.id AS cart_details_id,
  shop.id AS cart_id,
  e.name AS client_name,
  e.nif AS client_tin,
  e.addr AS client_address,
  CONCAT (e.zipcode, ' ', e.zipcodeext) AS client_zipcode,
  e.zipcodename AS client_location,
  c.printable_name_prt AS client_country,
  e.contact AS client_phone,
  CONCAT('') AS client_cell,
  e.email AS client_email,
  CONCAT('') AS notes,
  shop.end_time AS date_created,
  shop.end_time AS date_updated
FROM table_eshop shop
INNER JOIN entities e ON (e.id = shop.uid)
INNER JOIN system_table_countries c ON (c.id = e.country_id)
WHERE shop.id != ''
ORDER BY shop.id ASC
```

Os resultados aparecem todos bem no ecrã, mas gostaria de inserir os mesmos na tabela de destino.

**Detalhes da tabela de destino:**

- Nome:

  ```sql
  cart_details
  ```
- Campos:

  ```sql
  `cart_details_id`, `cart_id`, `client_name`, `client_tin`, `client_address`,
  `client_zipcode`, `client_location`, `client_country`, `client_phone`, `client_cell`,
  `client_email`, `notes`, `date_created`, `date_updated`
  ```

## Pergunta

Como posso inserir os resultados de uma consulta numa outra tabela?

Comment: @UtilizadorVotoANegativo: Uma explicação para o voto a negativo ajudar-me-ia a entender o que está mal com a pergunta de forma a melhorar a mesma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em MySQL, para inserir o resultado que obtemos de uma consulta à base de dados numa tabela da mesma base de dados, basta preceder a consulta que vamos realizar com a linha de inserção.

[Link para documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html). <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

**Para o teu caso em particular:**

```sql
INSERT INTO `cart_details` ( `cart_details_id` , `cart_id` , `client_name` , `client_tin` , `client_address` , `client_zipcode` , `client_location` , `client_country` , `client_phone` , `client_cell` , `client_email` , `notes` , `date_created` , `date_updated` )
SELECT
  shop.id AS cart_details_id,
  shop.id AS cart_id,
  e.name AS client_name,
  e.nif AS client_tin,
  e.addr AS client_address,
  CONCAT( e.zipcode, ' ', e.zipcodeext ) AS client_zipcode,
  e.zipcodename AS client_location,
  c.printable_name_prt AS client_country,
  e.contact AS client_phone,
  CONCAT( '' ) AS client_cell,
  e.email AS client_email,
  CONCAT( '' ) AS notes,
  shop.end_time AS date_created,
  shop.end_time AS date_updated
FROM table_eshop shop
INNER JOIN entities e ON ( e.id = shop.uid )
INNER JOIN system_table_countries c ON ( c.id = e.country_id )
WHERE shop.id != ''
ORDER BY shop.id ASC
```